# Get a specific part of a URL in C#

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I have a Url in a string variable.

Example format of the Urls I have are:

```
http://something.com/sites/collection
```

`http://something:33/sites/collection`,
`something:44/sites/collection`

Now I want to extract **"/sites/collection"** part from that url.

Comment: Did you tried applying `Regex`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a `System.Uri` instance and use the [`AbsolutePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absolutepath.aspx) property:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://something.com/sites/collection");
string path = uri.AbsolutePath;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the Path.  Load your URL into a `Uri` object and use the properties on that object.

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://something:33/sites/collection");
string path = uri.AbsolutePath;
```

I don't recommend using Regex when there's a simple framework class that gives you access to all the information you need about a URL.

Here's some more reading:

[Parts of a URL](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/seo-glossary-url-definitions/)

[System.Uri Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) (Poke around here for more information that you can glean from the URL)

[AbsolutePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absolutepath.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.Uri` class.

```
System.Uri uri = new System.Uri("http://something.com/sites/collection");
string path = uri.AbsolutePath;
```

Answer (score 0):

Load it into a URI object

```
Uri theUri = new Uri("http://something.com/sites/collection");
```

Then get the Absolute path

```
string x = theUri.AbsolutePath;
```